# Docker container fails to run, Error : python3: can't open file 'flask run --host=0.0.0.0': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to docker and I am trying to dockerize a python flask microservice. The docker file builds successfully but on running the container it gives an error :

```
python3: can't open file 'flask': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I am assuming there is some mistake in my docker file either in the COPY path, ENTRYPOINT or CMD i.e. the commands that I use to run the flask application. I am not able to figure out the mistake.

The directory structure on Ubuntu machine is:

```
/home/ubuntu/Docker/auth
```

The directory auth contains my Dockerfile and all other python flask files:

```
$ls 
Dockerfile   run.py    views.py     resources.py    models.py
```

run.py is the main python flask file for execution. I'm sure there is some syntax error in how I am executing the CMD command for the flask application and it is not able to find run.py for execution. I am not able to correct that error.

The image builds successfully. For running the container I use:

```
docker build <imageid>
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04

MAINTAINER xyz <xyz@yahoo.com>

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y software-properties-common vim \
    && add-apt-repository ppa:jonathonf/python-3.6 \
    && apt-get update -y \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential python3.6 python3.6-dev python3-pip 
       python3.6-venv \
    && pip3 install --upgrade pip

WORKDIR /auth
COPY . /auth

RUN pip3 install alembic==0.9.9 \
    && pip3 install Flask==1.0.2 \

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD [ "export","FLASK_APP=run.py" ]
CMD [ "set", "FLASK_APP=run.py" ]
CMD [ "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0" ]
```

Expected: Application should run on the container.
Actual: Python3: can't open file 'flask': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Attempting to `CMD` or `RUN` an `export` command is completely pointless. You should use `ENV` to set any environment variables. The purpose of `export` is to make variables visible to *children of the shell which exports* but the shell in which you `RUN` will never have any children, and certainly cannot set any variables in the parent Docker process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The best use for ENTRYPOINT is to set the image’s main command,
> allowing that image to be run as though it was that command (and then
> use CMD as the default flags).

https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#entrypoint

lots of people seem to miss this point about the `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` Dockerfile-instructions.

the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction supposed to run some executable, which should run every time you start the container, such as starting your server.

the `CMD` supposed to include the flags provided to that executable, so they can be easily overridden when running the container.

i am not sure you are supposed to have more then one `CMD` instruction. if you need to run commands during the build process, you can use the [`RUN`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#run) instruction - for example:

```
RUN mkdir some/dir
```

now:

> run.py is the main python flask file for execution

hence i suggest you define it as your entrypoint:

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "./run.py" ]
```

commands that you may also want to run every time the container starts, such as `flask run --host=0.0.0.0` you can:

- move that command to sit inside the `run.py` file

  or
- keep the `CMD [ "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0" ]` line. this command will be passed as an argument to the run.py entrypoint, so you may execute it in there. that way you can easily override the command when running the container with alternative arguments.

this stuff is also in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint):

> **Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact**
>
> Both CMD and ENTRYPOINT
> instructions define what command gets executed when running a
> container. There are few rules that describe their co-operation.
>
> Dockerfile should specify at least one of CMD or ENTRYPOINT commands.
>
> ENTRYPOINT should be defined when using the container as an
> executable.
>
> CMD should be used as a way of defining default arguments for an
> ENTRYPOINT command or for executing an ad-hoc command in a container.
>
> CMD will be overridden when running the container with alternative
> arguments.

Comment: Don't `RUN` an `export` - see my comment above.

Comment: thanks @tripleee, you are right. i didnt pay attention.

Comment: It's arguably the same with `set`. I'm guessing matobe the OP added his in desperation when `export` didn't work? I don't think it does anything useful actually.

Comment: i just wanted to show how to use the run instruction. @jaikumar may do whatever he likes with his enviroment variables.

Comment: *maybe - sorry, mobile keyboard ... Yeah, for demonstration you can `RUN echo` or whatever. Just don't expect it to leave any trace in the image.